# blender scale problem

Tags: objects

I want to duplicate a torus inwards but when I do the thickness of the torus decreases is there a way to get around this [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a scientific way to do it but you can do it visually: Choose the front view and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to have transparency, select the smaller torus and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> in order to fatten. You can precisely set the *Offset* in the Operator box if you want:

[image]

You could also have created these torus with a curve (create a *Curve > Circle*, then in *Edit* mode duplicate and scale):

[image]

Then bevel it, which makes it keep the same radius:

[image]

You can also use a simple circle and give it a triple circle as bevel *Object*:

[image]

Comment: I tried a circle curve and beveled it and when I try to duplicate and scale it gets smaller

Comment: create the 3 circles within the same curve object

Comment: thanks moonboots